# Add TouchListener in MPAndroidChart on marker Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener, mpandroidchart

Want to Add TouchListener in MPAndroidChart on marker Layout when user touch on marker (tvContent ) I want to show another activity.**

Values are set on marker but I want to implement Touch listener to show another activity.**

```
public class XYMarkerView extends MarkerView {
private TextView tvContent;
public RelativeLayout main;
private IAxisValueFormatter xAxisValueFormatter;
public Context mcontext;
private DecimalFormat format;

public XYMarkerView(Context context, IAxisValueFormatter xAxisValueFormatter) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_marker_view);
    mcontext = context;
    this.xAxisValueFormatter = xAxisValueFormatter;
    tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
    main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainmarker);

    format = new DecimalFormat("###.0");
    main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    main.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}


// callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
// content (user-interface)
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {

    tvContent.setText(" " + xAxisValueFormatter.getFormattedValue(e.getX(), null) + ", : " + format.format(e.getY()));
    main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ohhh!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        }
    });
    main.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
}
```

*Main Activity*

```
    XYMarkerView mv = new XYMarkerView(this, xAxisFormatter);
    mv.setChartView(mChart); // For bounds control
    mChart.setMarker(mv); // Set the marker to the chart
```

Comment: Waht have you tried so far, and what errors are you getting?

Comment: i add listners in Marker class but it will not work